# AWS CLI Inspector "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

While using the AWS Inspector service, I encountered the following error when trying to list findings using the aws inspector list-findings command:

```
$ aws inspector list-findings

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://inspector.<region>.amazonaws.com/"
```

**Steps I Tried to Solve the Issue:**

- I checked my AWS settings and configuration thoroughly, but everything seemed to be set up correctly.
- I made sure that the default region and profile I was using were accurate, and there were no issues there.
- Surprisingly, all my other AWS services were working fine without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that there is a solution to this problem by using aws inspector2 instead of the regular `aws inspector` command.

For anyone facing this issue, you can try using the `aws inspector2` command as an alternative to `aws inspector`. [Link to documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/inspector2/index.html).

The following command worked for me. The documentation was not pointing to a correct version to use.

```
$ aws inspector2 list-findings
```